# How can I fetch a partial git repository?

Tags: git

I am working in a project with a large git repository and many different teams. The repository makes heavy use of submodules. This makes even the most mundane tasks like a simple fetch a major annoyance, not only because the fetch takes ages, but also because the submodules outside of our own team tend to cause a lot of trouble.

So my question is whether it is possible to filter git fetches so that only the branches of my team are taken into account.

Comment: A `git fetch` *doesn't* fetch any submodules. It can still be pretty slow/heavy-going, if there are large objects. However, once you have an initial full clone, you can use that as a *reference clone* to make all subsequent separate clone operations very fast.

Comment: @torek I am not very familiar with the internals of submodules, but it was my observation that when I fetch a branch and that branch has a submodule version that I don't already have locally, that this version needs to be retrieved. After I filtered my fetches, the amount of submodule updates went down significantly along with the number of branches fetched, therefore my understanding was that fetch does need to retrieve submodules if a fetched branch demands it. Maybe I'm missing something. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The fetch step simply obtains commits and supporting objects within the repository. A submodule occurs when one repository *refers to* some other repository. In this case, the "outer" (or *superproject*) Git repository just holds the raw hash ID of some commit in the "inner" (submodule) Git repository. A `git fetch` in the superproject only updates the superproject itself: you must then have the superproject Git enter the submodule and run a *second* `git fetch` there. That's done by various operations including recursive checkout or `git submodule update`.

Comment: While any needed commits *will* have to be retrieved in order to use them, the *outer* `git fetch` doesn't *do it*. Limiting the *inner*, and later, `git fetch`, may be important, but needs to be done later, during the inner `git fetch`. But if you know what other repositories the outer repository will refer to, you can prepare initial reference clones of every repository involved. This gets ... hairy, as the submodule code doesn't know how to do that on its own.

Comment: @torek Not sure I understand. Maybe a specific question to clear that up: If I call a fetch, then all new branches will be retrieved, along with information about which submodules they use, right? My impression was that during that step, sometimes version conflicts of the submodules may appear, but I could be wrong. So I was struggling with two problems mainly: branch conflicts (cannot lock ref) and "dangling" submodules (after git submodule update, some submodules are not updated or local deletions are necessary), both are resolved by filtering fetches, but I may be mixing up the two effects.

Comment: *Branches* do not use submodules. *Commits* may contain *gitlinks*, but the existence of gitlink *G* for some hash ID *H* just means "hash *H* contains a gitlink". It's not until you `git checkout` commit *H* that the gitlink, which says "get me specific commit *G* from a submodule", comes into play. At this point—and *only* at this point—Git will try to turn the gitlink's path, as seen in Git's index, into a submodule name, as seen in the config or `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: So: when you run `git fetch`, your Git (your software working with your repository) calls up some other Git (their software on their repo). Your Git gets from their Git any commits they have, that you don't, that you need. These go into your repository, and your Git creates or updates *remote-tracking names* to let you find these commits. No submodule anything has occurred! You just have new commits; those may, or may not, have gitlinks in them.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is organised well, so that you can identify your team's branches by a unique string, then you can filter the branches you want to fetch.

The config file in `.git/config` controls which parts of the remote repository should be fetched.

The section often looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@myrepository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The last line filters which parts should be taken into account during a fetch.
The part before the colon describes what should be fetched from remote and the part after the colon describes where to put it locally

So in order to filter only certain parts from the repository structure. You can use wildcards to fetch whole subtrees, but also partial directory names.
Multiple fetch lines are allowed:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@myrepository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/feature/myteam*:refs/remotes/origin/feature/myteam*
    fetch = +refs/heads/release/*:refs/remotes/origin/release/*
```

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec